# laravel where condition for related eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller, relational-database

I have to Models `User` and `UserAttr`

User is like :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 2 | doe |

UserAttr is like

| id | user_id | job |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | seller |
| 2 | 2 | teacher |

them relation is :

for user :

```
    //User MODEL
    public function UserAttr(){
        return $this->hasOne(UserAttr::class);
    }
```

for UserAttr :

```
    //UserAttr MODEL
    public function UserAttr(){
             return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Inside of controller i want to return this

`Return all Users Where They job is Seller`

i try

```
$users = User::where(User::UserAttr()->where('job','teacher'));
return $users;
```

but it not works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 'where' requires two arguments. `where('column', 'value')`. Second, until you use a function dedicated for returning the results, like `find(1)`, `first()`, `get()`, you will always get a builder object.

In this particular case, you need to query the relationship. Something like this should work for you.

```
User::with('userAttr')->whereHas('userAttr', function($query){ 
   return $query->where('job', 'teacher');
})->get();
```

For reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence